# how to use dialerkeylistener in android

Tags: android

I want to set this format phone no 223-233-3334 for edit text when user typing in keyboard .i know i have to use dialerkeylistener and textfilter .can anybody give sample how to use dialerkeylistener to set format in android

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-NANP (http://www.howtocallabroad.com/nanp.html) countries to implement phone number formatting while user typing, you can use some workaround like this:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                String typedNum = yourEditText.getText().toString();
                if(typedNum.length() == 3)
                {
                    yourEditText.setText(typedNum + "-");
                yourEditText.setSelection(4);
                }
                else if(typedNum.length() == 7)
                {
                    yourEditText.setText(typedNum + "-");
                    yourEditText.setSelection(8);
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
```

Otherwise solution can be :

```
import android.telephony.PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher;
```

**OnCreate :**

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

If you like to format the number after user has entered the phone number:

```
  import android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils;
```

**OnCreate :**

```
PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(Editable text, int defaultFormattingType);
```

Comment: sharma its work in emulator but not work in device if device setting phone in india

Comment: Please see edited answer. I have made a workaround for your requirement. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Sorry, have you read the title of this question? I don't think your answer is the expected one.